# Modifying an existing ecore file?

Tags: eclipse, emf, ecore

I try to do a model-to-model transformation using Epsilon. The target model is UML.

If I validate the output model in Eclipse I get the following error message:

"Element 'Activity test' must be owned, but it has no owner."

So I tried to add a statement to my ETL file that adds owners for my activities.

But:

"Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'owner' is not a valid changeable feature"

1. Do I have to modify the UML ecore file in order to make 'owner' changeable? If so, how would I do that?
2. What exactly should be the owner of an activity? Another model element?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The feature `Element.owner` (which `Activity` inherits) is a *container* reference. In order to set it, you have to set the opposite, which is the *containment* reference `Element.ownedElement`. The activity should be contained in your root `Package` or `Model` in the feature `packagedElements`.